# How to listen for a zoom level change in Here Maps

Tags: here-api

I'd like to run some code when the zoom level changes on a map but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to listen for the change.

I've tried variations of the following without any luck:

```
map.addEventListener("zoomLevel",function(){...

map.addObserver("zoomLevel",function(){...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function () {

});
```

Comment: With "map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function (evt) {
console.log(evt);
});" You will get more details what has been changed (evt.newValue; evt.oldValue)